# how could i add a new menu in Word using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want to add a custom menu in Word, and on clicking on the menu item , my application should execute.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that because you mention menu, you are speaking of Word 2003. If you want to use C# for that, you may use VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) to do that, using the older version, VSTO 2005 SE. I have never done that for Word, but I did for Excel, and I think there shouldn't be much of a difference there. You will have to use Visual Studio 2008 for this, though; I believe VSTO 2005 SE is no longer supported in VS 2010.
If you are targeting Word 2007 or higher, you would have to use the Ribbon instead, as the Menu is gone.

Comment: I am targeting word 2007, how could i add a ribbon of my own?

Comment: Then it's even easier. Create a VSTO word add-in project in Visual Studio, it's a .NET add-in to Word; you can create a Ribbon control in that project fairly easily, and hook up Ribbon events to your code. The following example is for Excel, but should give you a good idea of what is involved: http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/create-excel-2007-vsto-add-in-ribbon.aspx